# SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'setPrototypeOf'

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I've created a react app using "create-react-app" command and updated all packages in package.json, App was not working in IE(any version) but after adding @babel/polyfil dependecy, it worked with IE-11, but facing problem with IE-10 and older version.
**SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'setPrototypeOf'**

Answer (score 0):

Create React App requires polyfills to work on Internet Explorer. You should follow [the official guide](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-app-polyfill/README.md) to make it work on IE 9, 10 or 11. At the time of this writing it requires the following steps:

Install `react-app-polyfill` via `npm` or `yarn`.

```
npm install react-app-polyfill
```

Import it in your code:

```
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie9';
// or
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
```